# Simple package imports resulting in divide by zero warnings

Tags: python

When I import many libraries (e.g. numpy, matplotlib, etc), I'm getting divide by zero warnings, in much the same way as would occur if I had screwed up an eqn in my code. While this doesn't stop me from using the package, it's pretty frustrating, and as I'm new to python and learning, I can't figure out how to suppress them.

For example, just running "import numpy" results in 12 warnings that are all similar to the below

```
C:\mydirectory\numpy\__init__.py:244: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in subtract
  if not abs(x.dot(x) - 2.0) < 1e-5:
C:\mydirectory\numpy\__init__.py:244: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in absolute
  if not abs(x.dot(x) - 2.0) < 1e-5:
```

Any easy way to fix?

Comment: Could you please include the whole error code?

Comment: This seems like an error in one of the packages you're importing, not much you can do about it.

Comment: Yes of course: I've included 3 of the 12 above as an example (only included 3 as its true for basically every single package outside of the standard library. @Johannes - apologies for my ignorance, but is there an easy way to at least suppress the warnings?

Comment: Try reinstalling numpy? This really shouldn't happen and if it keeps happening you could write an issue about it on numpy's github page, because it seems like it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could suppress all the warnings occurring from the different packages using warnings package. Just add below lines starting of your code.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```